# Add CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to MySQL record on update

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm updating MySQL records:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE nodes SET text='". $text . ..... "', datealtered='CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', ..... '") or die(mysql_error());
```

I set the type for datealtered in PHPMyAdmin to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. All of the other fields get updated, but the Date never gets updated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
datealtered='CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
```

Is trying to set `datealtered` to the literal string `'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'` not the value of the [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) function (AKA [`now()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)). Try dropping the single quotes to get at the current timestamp (rather than a string):

```
datealtered=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

MySQL tends to silently ignore errors so it is probably trying to interpret `'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'` as a date and silently failing.

And I hope you're properly escaping `$text` and friends to avoid SQL injection attacks and similar unpleasantness.